# finding ngrams with nltk in turkish text

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to find ngrams in a Turkish text which has unicode characters. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams

def find_bigrams():
    t = "çağlar boyunca geldik çağlar aktı gitti. çağlar aktı"
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
    bigrams = ngrams(token,2)
    for i in bigrams:
        print i

find_bigrams()
```

output:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I change the text like this:

```
t = "çağlar boyunca geldik çağlar aktı gitti"
```

output also changes:

```
('\xc3\xa7a\xc4\x9flar', 'boyunca')
('boyunca', 'geldik')
('geldik', '\xc3\xa7a\xc4\x9flar')
('\xc3\xa7a\xc4\x9flar', 'akt\xc4\xb1')
('akt\xc4\xb1', 'gitti')
```

How can I solve this unicode problem? And the other question is how can I convert these tokens to string (without `')` chars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't so much of a NLTK problem as a unicode problem.

This can be solved by adding the right import from `__future__`; in this case, you need `unicode_literals`.

Note this example from my Mac's install of Python 2.7.10:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> t = "çağlar boyunca geldik çağlar aktı gitti. çağlar aktı"
>>> print(t)
çağlar boyunca geldik çağlar aktı gitti. çağlar aktı
```

`bigrams` is a list of tuples, so to remove the parens, you can iterate over each pair in the list.

```
>>> tup = ("hello", "world")
>>> print tup
(u'hello', u'world')
>>> l = [tup]
>>> for i in l:
...   print(i)
... 
(u'hello', u'world')
>>> for i,j in l:
...   print("{0} {1}".format(i, j))
... 
hello world
```

Combining these ideas in your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.util import ngrams

def find_bigrams():
    t = "çağlar boyunca geldik çağlar aktı gitti. çağlar aktı"
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(t)
    bigrams = ngrams(token,2)
    for i, j in bigrams:
        print("{0} {1}".format(i, j))

find_bigrams()
```

Comment: it works with this string, but when i try to import large string from a text file i still get the first error

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: this one is worked thank you t = codecs.open('siirclear.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()

Comment: I was just about to suggest that. Glad you got it working.